# jquery, cannot select a TR after DOM manipulation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

I hope somebody can help me here as I cannot figure this out. 
I have a table showing usernames. When I click a TR line it fetches the information by an ajax request to a PHP page that gets the content from SQL and passes it on to a form.

When the form is updated and saved the reverse is happening, sent to a PHP page by ajax, witch updates the SQL.

Then when the update is done i want the list to update it self without refreshing the page. I got this working. It is fetching the new saved content from the DB by ajax/php, and then populates the table by using .append.

BUT the problem is when the table is updated it is not possible anymore to select a TR in the table.

This is maby confusingly explained..

I have checked how the DOM looks before and after the change (with Coda/DOM tree) and they are similar at least in my eyes:

**BEFORE MANUPULATION:**

```
<table id="brukere" cellpadding="8"> 
<thead>
    <tr><td>Brukernavn</td></tr></thead>
<tbody> 
<tr id="1" onmouseover="changebgcolor(this)" onmouseout="restorebgcolor(this)"     style="background-color: white; ">
    <td>Name 1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2" onmouseover="changebgcolor(this)" onmouseout="restorebgcolor(this)" style="background-color: white; ">
    <td>Name 2</td>
</tr>    
</tbody> 
</table>
```

**AFTER MANIPULATION:**

```
<table id="brukere" cellpadding="8"> 
<thead>
    <tr><td>Brukernavn</td></tr></thead>
<tbody> 
<tr id="1" onmouseover="changebgcolor(this)" onmouseout="restorebgcolor(this)">
    <td>Name 1</td> 
</tr>
<tr id="2" onmouseover="changebgcolor(this)" onmouseout="restorebgcolor(this)">
    <td>Name 2</td> 
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

The code I am using that work before the DOM is manipulated to select the TR is:

```
$("#brukere tr")
      .click(function() {
```

To refresh the table I first clear the TR`s:

```
$("#brukere").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

And then append, the new content (data) comes as HTML from the PHP file:

```
$("table tbody").append(data),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, when you do

```
$("#brukere").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

you remove the `tr`, together with its click handler.  So you either need to attach a new click handler afterwards (to the newly inserted element) or you need to use a delegate on an element that doesn't get removed, such as:

```
$("#brukere").on('click', 'tr', function() {...});
```

This will attach a `click` handler to the `#brukere` table.  However, the anonymous function only gets executed if the click originated from a child `tr`.  And since you never remove the table itself, that click handler never gets removed.

Comment: Aha, I get what youre saying! How would I format this insted of the one i have?   
  $("#brukere tr")
   .click(function() {
    $.ajax({

Comment: Just like I showed you above:  `$("#brukere").on('click', 'tr', function() { $.ajax(...); });`

Comment: PERFECT! Wish I asked before, would have saved me DAYS of scratching my head! Thank you so much :)